# como subo un archivo txt (por ejemplo)a una api?

Tags: javascript, html, api

hola amigos tengo una duda,como subo un archivo txt por ejemplo, a una api? tengo el html pero no tengo idea como subirlo a alguna api

```
 <div id="content-wrapper">

      <div class="container-fluid">

        <H1 align="left"><strong>Carga de Contribuyentes</strong></H1>
           
          <div class="form-group" style="text-align: center; margin: 50px 0" ;>
          <label for="ejemplo_archivo_1">Subir archivo</label>
          <input type="file" id="ejemplo_archivo_1">
       
        <button align="center" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="BotonCargaDeContribuyentes">Cargar archivo</button> </div>
```

Comment: Por favor evita ese tipo de ediciones pues por ejemplo dejas fuera de contexto la respuesta que te dieron

Answer (score 4):

Hola muy buenas Rodrigo.

La verdad que para subirlo a una API, es bastante relativo dependiendo de lo que quieras hacer y a dónde lo quisieras enviar, si a Firebase Storage, una API de archivos o hasta tu propia API.

### Pasos.

Lo primero que se debería de hacer, quieras subirlo a donde quieras subirlo, es handlear el evento change de ese input, para de esa manera, detectar, validar y guardar el archivo.

Aquí te brindo un ejemplo básico de cómo hacerlo en vainilla JS:

```js
//seleccionamos el input
const input = document.querySelector('#idDeMiInput');

//añadimos el evento change la input
input.addEventListener('change', ()=> {
   console.log('el input está cambiando');
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="idDeMiInput">
</body>
</html>
```

De esa manera ya podemos detectar cuando el input esté cambiando y hacer lo que queramos, en este caso que quieres subir un archivo txt, te voy a mostrar un ejemplo de cómo validar y guardar ese archivo:

```js
//guardamos el input
const input = document.querySelector('#idDeMiInput');

//agregamos el evento change
input.addEventListener('change', () => {
  //almacenamos el archivo
  const file = input.files[0];

  //validamos la extensión del archivo
  if (file.type !== 'text/plain') {
    alert('Por favor ingresa un archivo .txt válido!!');
    return;
  }

  //validamos que el archivo no sea mayor a 4MB
  if(file.size > 4000000){
    alert('Por favor, ingresa un archivo no mayor a 4MB');
    return;
  }

  alert('Todo correcto !!');
  console.log(file);
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="idDeMiInput" accept="text/plain">
</body>
</html>
```

Como puedes ver lo primero que estamos haciendo es guardar el archivo, para acceder a este simplemete accedemos a la propiedad `.files` del input, y el archivo debe de estar en la poscición `0`, osea en `.files[0]`.

Luego, si mandas este archivo por consola, puedes ver sus diferentes propiedades con las que lo puedes validar, en este caso yo he validado la extensión y también el tamaño, pero ya es tu gusto si quieres validar más cosas.

Por último, lo que por lo general se hace, es mandar el archivo por medio de una petición `multipart/form-data` (esto último si depende mucho de donde lo quieras subir, por lo general cada API tiene su documentación, te recomiendo mirarla) de la siguiente manera:

```js
//guardamos el input
const input = document.querySelector('#idDeMiInput');

//agregamos el evento change
input.addEventListener('change', () => {
  //almacenamos el archivo
  const file = input.files[0];

  //validamos la extensión del archivo
  if (file.type !== 'text/plain') {
    alert('Por favor ingresa un archivo .txt válido!!');
    return;
  }

  //validamos que el archivo no sea mayor a 4MB
  if (file.size > 4000000) {
    alert('Por favor, ingresa un archivo no mayor a 4MB');
    return;
  }

  //creamos una instancia de Form Data
  const formData = new FormData();
  //añadimos el archivo a esa data
  formData.append('file', file);

  //creamos la request
  const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  //indicamos el método y la ruta de la petición
  req.open('POST', 'https://la-url-de-la-api-o-el-endpoint');
  //seteamos la cabecera para enviar este tipo de archivos
  req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');

  //seteamos un evento para cuando la petición cambie
  req.onreadystatechange = () => {
    //si todo es correcto, consoleamos la respuesta de la API
    if (req.readyState === 4 && req.status === 200) {
      console.log(JSON.parse(req.responseText));
    }
  };

  //enviamos la petición
  req.send(formData);
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="idDeMiInput" accept="text/plain">
</body>
</html>
```

Como pudiste ver, en el anterior ejemplo hemos enviado el archivo nativamente con vainilla JS, pero puedes utilizar cualquier llibrería que quisieras. En mi caso yo siempre utilizo `axios`, pero ya eso es gusto tuyo.

Espero haberte ayudado !!

Links de referencia:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/alert

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/File

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/accept

Comment: Hola @RodrigoCamacho, perdón por no haberte respondido, no había entrado a stack, por favor, si puedes mandar el error sería genial. si me dices que te dá un error en el addEventListener, probablemente sería por algún error de sintaxis o que no estás seleccionando bien el input, pero como te dije, lo mejor es que mandes por aquí el error completo y vemos que es lo que pasa